# Adding ListView Items in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am sorry if this a repeat but I have searched here and Google and everything comes up with older code.

I have created a ListView with 2 columns.  I am trying to add items to the ListView.  My code:

```
for (intDisplayCnt = 0; intDisplayCnt < intFieldLengths.Length; intDisplayCnt++)
            {
                string[] strRow = { "Field" + (intDisplayCnt + 1), intFieldLengths[intDisplayCnt].ToString() };
                //aryListItems[0, 0] = "Field" + (intDisplayCnt + 1);
                //aryListItems[0, 1] = intFieldLengths[intDisplayCnt].ToString();
                //ListViewItem.
                lvwFieldInfo.Items.Add(strRow);
            }
```

The code executes but the output is String[] Array    String[]  Array

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Kent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what XAML code you are using for your ListView. But you might consider looking at below example and see if it fits your requirement.

```
// xmal code    
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FieldId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FieldId}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FieldLength" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FieldLength}"/>
         </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

    // define your custom listview item class
    public class MyFieldListViewItem
    {
        public string FieldId { get; set; }

        public string FieldLength { get; set; }
    }

    // when adding the item
    for (intDisplayCnt = 0; intDisplayCnt < intFieldLengths.Length; intDisplayCnt++)
    {
        var fieldId = "Field" + (intDisplayCnt + 1);
        var fieldLen = intFieldLengths[intDisplayCnt].ToString();
        lvwFieldInfo.Items.Add(new MyFieldListViewItem { FieldId = fieldId, FieldLength = fieldLen });
    }
```

Comment: #woodykiddy that worked perfectly!  Thank you.  Now one other question,  Is there away to have borders on the rows and columns?

Comment: you can try to define the style in ItemContainerStyle, something like this, `<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>`

Comment: #woodykiddy, is there a way to do each column so I have a vertical border between columns?

Comment: i will point you to this link so you can take a look at it yourself. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dcf248b4-34c8-4d23-bdcd-f10f33c324f5/how-to-add-vertical-line-for-listview?forum=wpf. Hope it helps. Also if you are happy with my original answer, please mark it. Thanks.

Comment: #woodykiddy I am having a hard time getting the vertical line to show up using this code.  Do you have any working examples?

Comment: http://matthiasshapiro.com/2007/12/11/how-do-i-set-up-grid-lines-for-my-listview/  Take a look at this. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: #woodykiddy I have tried this but I can't use it.  I am using VisualStudio Community 2015 and .NET 4.5.2.  When I enter this row:

<DataTemplate x:Key=”MyDataTemplate“>

I get an error because Key is not an option for x:.  I tried changing it to x:Name="MyDataTemplate" then this line has an error:

<GridViewColumn Header=”Whatever” CellTemplate=”{DynamicResource MyDataTemplate}“ />

I even just tried <DataTemplate> but it didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does anyone have any other ideas on how I can get a column separator in my listview?  All my research brings up code that appears to be an older version of .NET and doesn't seem to work for me.